# auth()->user()->pUserId makes Attempt to read property "pUserId" on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I have a problem where i can't get the pUserId from database when using authentication

Here's the controller(Home Controller):

```
function index(){
    $id = Auth::user()->pUserId; //Here's the main problem
    $profiles = profiles::where('pUserId',$id)->first();
    return view('home', compact('profiles'));
    // return view('home');
}
```

auth.php(config):

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
]
```

User.php(model)(default by laravel):

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'profiles';
    protected $guarded = [''];
```

I've already tried without using controller and straight to .blade.php and the error is still the same

```
@auth
<div class="header-control">
    <a href="">{{ auth()->user()->pUserId }}</a> //main problem
</div>
@endauth
```

[The Error Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNbFh.png)

Here's the route:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/', 'LoginController@index')->middleware('guest');
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@index')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login/authenticate', 'LoginController@authenticate')->middleware('guest');
```

Login Controller:

```
function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $login = $request->validate([
        'pUserId' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt($login))
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->intended('/home');
    }
    else
    {
        return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
    }
}
```

There's a several pUserId in profiles tables, but just said "property "pUserId" on null" when using

```
auth()->user()->pUserId or 
$id = Auth::user()->pUserId;
```

Auth:attempt($login) is successfully working, i just don't understand it doesn't work in Home Controller

migrations:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('pUserId',5)->primary();
        $table->string('pNamaLengkap', 255);
        $table->enum('pJobDescription', ['Full Stack Developer','Backend Developer','Frontend Developer']);
        $table->enum('pUnitKerja', ['Talent Management','Company Management','Customer Management']);
        $table->enum('pDirectorate',['Human Resources','Company Profile','Stabilitas Sistem Keuangan','Sistem Pengelolaan','Pendukung Kebijakan']);
        $table->string('password', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

[DB profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBu3g.png)

Comment: please share your table 's screenshot

Comment: It's going to be your middlewares as it is returning null for auth()->user().

Comment: yes i thought that it might be problem in middleware but i don't really understand where to use it or change it @Urudin

Comment: i don't think the problems is in the table because my Auth::attempt is working, but i will give the screenshot and the migrations @Kashan Baig

Comment: This means that `Auth::user()` is null, in other words; you arent authenticated.

Comment: Yes i already checked it, dd(Auth::user()) is null, can you explain me why? because i think i already authenticated by login controller or maybe it's just my imagination @frogeyedman

Comment: In your `User` model, did you specify the primary key like `protected $primaryKey = 'pUserId';` ?

Comment: @danielleander then make 100% sure the Auth::attempt succeeds, add a log, dd or something inside that if statement.

Comment: @Phil your ideas worked, thank you very much, but i don't know why there's this message "Route [login] not defined." but when i try the second times it worked fine

Comment: Ok. I leave this suggest as answer to close this question.

Comment: @danielleander I usually just go with Laravel's auth, so I'm just guessing, but why you use guest middleware? Basically there should be a web middleware for all, and an auth middleware for auth protected routes for a simple auth mechanism. And instead of saying ->middleware('guest') for each of your routes you should go with route groups (This is not the cause of ur problem, but it makes things cleaner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your user model, specify the primary key if you don't use `id` as the primary key:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'pUserId';
```